# Please tell me the way to use CRF++ on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nlp, crf++

Please tell me the way to use CRF++ on visual studio 2013.

OS:Windows 7 64 bit

SDK:Visual Studio 2013

How to use CRF++-0.54 on Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I build CRF++, but it is error.
tagger.cpp(57) [feature_index_->open(model.c_str(), 0)] feature_index.cpp(105) [
mmap_.open(filename1)] z:\proj\crfpp\mmap.h(117) [hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE]
 CreateFile() failed: model